# Text from website appears as Gibberish instead of Hebrew

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I'm trying to get a string from a website. I use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module to send the `GET` request.

```
text = requests.get("http://example.com") #send GET requests to the website
print text.text #print the variable
```

However, for some reason, the text appears in Gibberish instead of Hebrew:

```
<div>
<p>×©×¨×ª</p>
</div>
```

Tough when I sniff the traffic with Fiddler or view the website in my browser, I see it in Hebrew:

```
<div>
<p>שרת</p>
</div>
```

By the way, the `html` code contains meta-tag that defines the encoding, which is `utf-8`.
I tried to encode the text to `utf-8` but it still in gibberish. I tried to deocde it using `utf-8`, but it throws `UnicodeEncodeError` exception.
I declared that I'm using `utf-8` in the first line of the script.
Moreover, the problem is also happend when I send the request with the built in `urllib` module.

I read the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), but still couldn't manage to fix it. I also read many threads here (both about the `UnicodeEncodeError` exception and about why hebrew turns into gibberish in Python) but I still couldn't manage to fix it up.

I'm using Python 2.7.9 on a Windows machine. I'm running my script in the Python IDLE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should  use .content instead of text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server isn't declaring the encoding correctly.

```
>>> print u'×©×¨×ª'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
שרת
```

Set `text.encoding` before accessing `text.text`.

```
text = requests.get("http://example.com") #send GET requests to the website
text.encoding = 'utf-8' # Correct the page encoding
print text.text #print the variable
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! I would never find it myself. Thanks again!